# Python 3 script doesn't work when Unicode escaped string is passed as a command line argument

Tags: python, unicode, escaping

I am using Python 3.3.x and Windows 7 64-bit. I have to process unicode escaped strings in my program. Strings which are represented such as: "\u0000N@@^J\u0007QEA\u0001V^DNK\u000b"

When I define such strings directly in the code and process them, it works properly.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

vv = "\u0000N@@^J\u0007QEA\u0001V^DNK\u000b"
kk = 27
```

However, when I pass them through the command line as a parameter, it does not work as expected.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

# vv = unicode escaped string
vv = sys.argv[1]

kk = int(sys.argv[2])
```

And I invoke the script as shown below:

```
python code.py "\u0000N@@^J\u0007QEA\u0001V^DNK\u000b" 27
```

I tried printing the string back to the console and it prints it exactly like this: \u0000N@@^J\u0007QEA\u0001V^DNK\u000b

I am not sure what is the issue here. I am using MS DOS as the console.

```
ver command output from the console

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

Comment: when you send it as argument then it treats \ as normal char, not unicode. In code you get the same result when you use "raw" string with prefix `r` - like `vv = r"\u0000N@@^J\u0007QEA\u0001V^DNK\u000b"`

Comment: So is there a way to send the unicode escaped string as an argument and make the code treat it as a unicode escaped string and not a raw string?

Comment: try `print( vv.encode().decode('unicode_escape') )`

Comment: yep - re-encoding the string with unicode_escape is the answer here - and you can word that as a proper answer.